# Python TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable when using list comprehension inside for loop

Tags: python, typeerror, shadowing

I'm trying to generate a list of strings using a list comprehension, where the string is formatted using f-strings:

```
features = [("month", (1, 12)), ("day_of_year", (1, 365))]
for feature, range in features:
  cols= [f"transformed_{feature}_period_{i:02d}" for i in range(12)]
```

If I run this code, I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 3
      1 features = [("month", (1, 12)), ("day_of_year", (1, 365))]
      2 for feature, range in features:
----> 3     cols= [f"transformed_{feature}_period_{i:02d}" for i in range(12)]

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I still get the error even if I remove the variables from the string:

```
for feature, range in features:
  cols= ["transformed_feature_period" for i in range(12)]
```

I don't understand why the interpreter is complaining that I'm trying to call a tuple. I'm able to perform other operations, such as actual function calling and asserts inside the outer for loop, but I keep bumping into this error when trying to use a list comprehension.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's why you should not use variable name that shadows buitin function name

Comment: It's because `range` is a built-in type. Try renaming `range` to `rng`.

Comment: if you do this `for feature, range in features` then you have replaced the builtin `range` function with your loop variable, so you can no longer call the real `range` function

Comment: also how do you expect a first `range` (local var) and second `range` (builtin) to work together?

Comment: @GodIsOne please do not use code formatting for technical terms - it is for things that would actually appear in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually use the range,

```
for feature, _ in features:
    ...
```

If you only care about the endpoints of the range,

```
for feature, (start, stop) in features:
    ...
```

If you really need a reference to the tuple as a whole, pick a name that doesn't shadow the built-in type you use later:

```
for feature, feature_range in features:
    ...
```

I don't recommend using `builtins.range` to access the shadowed type when it's simpler to provide a more accurate name for the index variable in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you change your Jupyter notebook or anyother idle** you are using because the `range()` function will become `tuple` as it will override the `buitin range` .

```
features = [("month", (1, 12)), ("day_of_year", (1, 365))]
for feature, r in features:
    print(feature, range(int(r[0]),int(r[1])))

#output

month range(1, 12)
day_of_year range(1, 365)
```

So, this will be the final code:

```
features = [("month", (1, 12)), ("day_of_year", (1, 365))]
for feature, r in features:
  cols= [f"transformed_{feature}_period_{i:02d}" for i in range(int(r[0]),int(r[1]))]

print(cols)
['transformed_day_of_year_period_01',
 'transformed_day_of_year_period_02',
 'transformed_day_of_year_period_03',
 'transformed_day_of_year_period_04',
 'transformed_day_of_year_period_05',
  ....
 'transformed_day_of_year_period_364']
```

Comment: Simply changing the `range` variable name to something else worked, _after_ I restarted the ipython kernel.